# Cognos 10 Authentication and Styling

Tags: javascript, css, cognos-10

I'm creating reports for my client, I'm asked to create 41 report for 12 departments, each department have a head and users (employees)

**Authentication**

All employees are supposed to access Cognos using a webpage example(localhost/reports), I've created this page that redirects automatically to a blank report so the user can authenticate since I use Active Directory for authentication, this page is supposed to have links to reports but as a user login in I want to hide reports between departments where each department can only track their reports not all of them as well as regular users are supposed to view specific reports not all of them as department heads can see all the reports, I was able to fetch the user GUID with CAMIDList I want to handle what to show on the reports page using javascript but these groups are dynamic so I'm keeping them in a json file where each group has its own GUID, I'm not sure what's the best way to create a webpage having all links to reports and depending on the user group we can show/hide these links and please note that we need SSO enabled so what's better to use Cognos Authentication or Websphere Authentication (j security check)

**Styling**

Regarding styles, I'm supposed to customize the native look and feel of the reports to a custom one for the client, by styling the lists, crosstabs, footers and headers with css how is it possible

**Wrapping Up**

Here are my questions

**1: How can I create a webpage that show report links depending on logged in user?**

**2: What's the best way to style cognos reports with css?**

Software Installed:

1- IBM Cognos BI 10.2.2

2- IBM HTTP Server

3- IBM Websphere

Thanks in advance and sorry for my weak English writing structure

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you can use IBM Cognos BI 10.2.2 level itself as you are using active directory.You can add permissions at folder level/each report report level so that one can restrict based on the user id to view reports.

Comment: I've done that until my Project Manager asked me what if any department head requested to evaluate their employees without them knowing, we want to show/hide reports based on their roles on webpages level (handling it with javascript)